# C# warning system xml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I keep getting this warning all the time.

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Xml.Linq, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, Retargetable=Yes". Choosing "System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

I have not added any dependency or anything.

Comment: Two things you are referencing have these conflicting dependencies.

Comment: To add on to Charlie: it might be that another dependency (one via NuGet) references System.Xml.Linq 2.0.5.0. Please note that that version is way too old to be used and that the package that uses it might be out of data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .csproj file - you will likely find both of these entered there. Leave the one you want and delete the other and the warning should disappear.

Comment: I don't see the version in those files. On only see that some project reference it.